# Prevent log4j to evaluate traces with higher level than global

Tags: scala, log4j

In my project we are managing logs with log4j v1.2.17 and we noticed that, although not showing up, traces with level `DEBUG` (higher level than project global configuration, `INFO`) are evaluated (for instance, a dataframe row count inside a `log.debug()` call)

Is there any way to avoid evaluation at all of arguments of higher level traces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either upgrade to Log4J 2.x or wrap your log statements with a check for that particular log level. There is a section in the docs that describes the way how to do it in v1 vs v2: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/api.html

See "Java 8 lambda support for lazy logging". And depending on the version of Scala you use you might have to go with the old style anyway.

Comment: Looks like the way to go. I'll wait just in case someone comes with a better idea but this certainly looks like the kind of behavior I want

Comment: If none of that is what you want to do then you could also create a wrapper that uses Scala's call-by-name parameter syntax.

Comment: Just for the record, I used Scala's call-by-name parameter syntax to create a wrapper for logs and it works flawlessly. It defines the same methods (debug, info, ...)